# Cannot (mouse) paste utf8 into ssh terminal

Tags: command-line, ssh, paste, chinese, utf-8

I can do Mouse-Middle-Click paste everywhere except my Oracle cloud server, which is running Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS --

Everywhere, if I run `date` under `LANG=zh_CN.utf8` environment and I'll get:

```
$ date
2023年 03月 18日 星期六 15:01:11 EDT
```

I can then mouse ***select*** the Chinese/utf8 string `星期六` and Mouse-Middle-Click ***paste*** into my xterm / terminal, like:

```
$ echo 星期六
星期六
```

I can do this everywhere except my Oracle cloud. If I tried that, instead of `echo 星期六` showing up on my command line, I'm getting:

[image]

So I'm thinking there must be something odd with my Oracle cloud configuration, as I can do it locally or even on another remote server that is also running Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, and all my home environment are the same across all of them. My Oracle cloud server displays Chinese/utf8 strings/filenames just fine though.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are the outputs of the `locale` command similar on all Ubuntu systems?

Comment: More or less @FedKad. All my systems have `zh_CN.utf8` locales, while the working remote server doesn't even have any zh_CN utf8 locale, and I just use C.utf8.